# Dynamic variables from hosts

Tags: ansible

When executing the role, it is necessary that the names of hostnames be substituted into the variables. It is also important to take into account the number of hosts and the places in the variables where they are substituted. Is it possible to do this only by means of ansible?

Example:
(host.ini)

```
host1 ansible_host='10.33.15.15' ansible_ssh_user='ben'

host2 ansible_host='10.33.15.16' ansible_ssh_user='ben'

host3 ansible_host='10.33.15.17' ansible_ssh_user='ben'

host4 ansible_host='10.33.15.18' ansible_ssh_user='ben'

host5 ansible_host='10.33.15.19' ansible_ssh_user='ben'
...
...
```

Example:
(roles/post_install/defaults/main.yml)

if the input is Only: host1 - only monitoring was deployed

```
  monitoring:
    nodes: ['host1']
  logging:
    nodes: []
```

If the input is host1 / host2
In this case, these same sections were:

```
  monitoring:
    nodes: ['host1']
  logging:
    nodes: ['host2']
```

if the input is host1 / host2 / host3
In this case, these same sections were:

```
monitoring:
    nodes: ['host1', 'host2']
  logging:
    nodes: ['host3']
```

if the input is host1 / host2 / host3 / host4
In this case, these same sections were:

```
monitoring:
    nodes: ['host1', 'host2']
  logging:
    nodes: ['host3', 'host4']
```

if the input is host1 / host2 / host3 / host4 / host5
In this case, these same sections were:

```
monitoring:
    nodes: ['host1', 'host2', 'host5']
  logging:
    nodes: ['host3', 'host4']
```

if the input is host1 / host2 / host3 / host4 / host5 / ... / ... / ...
In this case, these same sections were:

```
monitoring:
    nodes: ['host1', 'host2', 'host5', ...]
  logging:
    nodes: ['host3', 'host4' ...]
```

Comment: What you're asking is unclear. Please see [ask] and pay attention to the section about [mre]

Answer (score 1):

Put the declarations below into the vars. For example, into the *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/nodes.yml 
len: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|length }}"
rem: "{{ len|int % 4 }}"
bat: "{{ range(len|int - rem|int)|batch(2) }}"
_idx: |
  0:
    mon: []
    log: []
  1:
    mon: [-1]
    log: []
  2:
    mon: [-2]
    log: [-1]
  3:
    mon: [-3, -2]
    log: [-1]
  default:
    mon: {{ bat[0::2]|flatten }}
    log: {{ bat[1::2]|flatten }}
idx: "{{ _idx|from_yaml }}"
nodes: "{{ (len|int > 3)|
           ternary([idx[rem|int], idx.default]|combine(list_merge='prepend'),
                    idx[rem|int]) }}"
monitoring:
  nodes: "{{ nodes.mon|map('extract', ansible_play_hosts_all)|list }}"
logging:
  nodes: "{{ nodes.log|map('extract', ansible_play_hosts_all)|list }}"
```

Then, given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
[test]
host1
host2
host3
...
host17
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          monitoring:
            nodes: {{ monitoring.nodes|to_yaml }}
          logging:
            nodes: {{ logging.nodes|to_yaml }}
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit test[0:8]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    monitoring:
      nodes: [host1, host2, host5, host6, host9]
  
    logging:
      nodes: [host3, host4, host7, host8]
```

The maximal number of hosts is limited by the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit test[0:99]

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: |-
    monitoring:
      nodes: [host1, host2, host5, host6, host9, host10, host13, host14, host17]
  
    logging:
      nodes: [host3, host4, host7, host8, host11, host12, host15, host16]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, but I showed an example on three hosts, but what if there are more than three?

Comment: How should I know what you want `if there are more than three`? The question will be closed If you don't [edit] it and make it [mre].

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm asking a question first. Your answer already solved my problem, but I would like to know how it is possible to pass a dynamic number of variables from the host file.

Comment: I added an example.